# Outlook and macros. Cannot change folder or search

Tags: vba, outlook

I've made a small macro to count how many unread emails I have in my inbox. Then I send some data to a serial port and control a traffic light.

I have a problem with my macro, it has a while loop and is constantly checking the inbox. There is a DoEvents in the loop and it all works nice an smooth. All except that while the macro is running;

-If I click on an unread email to read it, then click on another email, the previous email should now be marked as read. This does not happen, I have to manually mark it as read or double click to open the email.

-I cannot use the search feature, it will just wait until I stop the macro from running.

-I cannot change the folder I am looking at until I stop the macro.

How can I periodically count how many unread emails I have without using a loop in my macro?

I've looked at creating a new thread (not possible in outlook), and using timers (crashes often, timer seems unpredictable).

```
'Checks for unread email and sets Trafic Light color
Sub CheckMail()
runner = 1
MailTemp = -1
While (runner)
    Const olFolderInbox = 6
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    objNamespace.Logon "Default Outlook Profile", , False, True
    Set objFolder = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    If MailTemp <> objFolder.UnReadItemCount Then
        MailTemp = objFolder.UnReadItemCount

        If objFolder.UnReadItemCount = 0 Then
            Shell "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\Miles Cave\TrafficLight\USB\Mail_0.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus
        End If

        If objFolder.UnReadItemCount = 1 Then
            Shell "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\Miles Cave\TrafficLight\USB\Mail_1.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus
        End If

        If objFolder.UnReadItemCount > 1 Then
            Shell "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\Miles Cave\TrafficLight\USB\Mail_2.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus
        End If
    End If
    DoEvents
Wend
End Sub

'Sets Trafic Light to off and stops CheckMail
Sub StopMail()
    Shell "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\Miles Cave\TrafficLight\USB\Lights off.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus
    runner = 0
End Sub
```

Here is the code I have. In CheckMail() there are 5 lines of code to get the number of unread email followed by an if to check if the number of unread emails as changed and 3 options of what to do depending on the number of emails.

StopMail() Simply stops the While loop in CheckMail().

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869662.aspx)/[FindNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff862482.aspx) or [Restrict](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869597.aspx) methods of the Items class to find all unread items. For example, the Restrict method applies a filter to the Items collection, returning a new collection containing all of the items from the original that match the filter. So then you can simple use the [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff868906.aspx) property of the Items class.

Also pay your attention to the [AdvancedSearch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219884.aspx) method of the Namespace class. It allows to run the search on another thread and get the number of unread items in multiple folders easily.

Use the following search criteria = `"[UnRead] = true"`.

You may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [Advanced search in Outlook programmatically: C#, VB.NET](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/)

Comment: Hi Eugene, I cannot use he built in search tool in Outlook. I am not trying to search with code. I'm having problems with the While loop not letting me use outlook functions normally. Thanks for the input

Comment: The VBA code is run on the main thread. You can't do anything in Outlook until the code stops/ends. Even in Outlook add-in it is not recommended, Outlook 2013 may throw exceptions in such case. The only possible way is to use a low-level API - Extended MAPI for running the code in the background. Note, the AdvancedSearch method searches items in the background, so you may try it first.

Answer (score 0):

You could trigger without a timer or a while loop in at least two ways.

1 - when mail received with ItemAdd

or

2 - when a mail's unread status changes to read with the ItemChange event, like this

In ThisOutlookSession

```
Private WithEvents checkMailItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim ns As Namespace
    Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set checkMailItems = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub checkMailItems_ItemChange(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is mailItem And Item.UnRead = False Then CheckMail
End Sub
```

In a regular module

```
Sub CheckMail()

    Dim objNameSpace As Namespace
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim uIC As Long

    Set objNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    uIC = objFolder.UnReadItemCount

    Select Case uIC

    Case 0
        Debug.Print "Inside CheckMail - uIC = " & uIC
        'Shell "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\Miles Cave\TrafficLight\USB\Mail_0.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus

    Case 1
        Debug.Print "Inside CheckMail - uIC = " & uIC
        'Shell "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\Miles Cave\TrafficLight\USB\Mail_1.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus

    Case Is > 1
        Debug.Print "Inside CheckMail - uIC = " & uIC
        'Shell "C:\Users\cave\Desktop\Miles Cave\TrafficLight\USB\Mail_2.bat", vbMinimizedNoFocus

    End Select

ExitRoutine:
    Set objNameSpace = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing

    Debug.Print "Procedure CheckMail is done."

End Sub
```